# Отправка Ajax запроса в модуль OpenCart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, opencart

Как передать POST параметр через ajax  в файл controller модуля OpenCart ?

Как работать с Ajax знаю, как  параметры передать, как принять знаю, но как обратится к нужному файлу в OpenCart?

При попытках обращения по "url:'  скрипт выдает ошибку (not found )404

Обсуждение на форуме [OpencartForum](https://opencartforum.com/topic/119828-otpravka-ajax-zaprosa-v-modul-opencart/)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, что метод-ендпоинт, к которому стучит ajax, содержит аргументы. В таком случае ответ всегда будет 404.

```
publick function someMethod($args)
{
    ...
```

Передавая post в такой метод, не надо прописывать аргументы. В теле метода необходимо обрабатывать $post

```
publick function someMethod()
{
    if (isset($this->request->post['some_variable'])) {
        ...
```